# Do I need to remove NSMutablearray objects before NULL/deleting NSMutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

```
NSMutableArray *thisArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
```

Do I need to delete any objects before deleting thisArray?

```
thisArray = NULL;
```

Comment: no, you don't need to do that

Comment: No, you do not.  When the array's destructor runs (as a result of ARC processing) it will delete the references and, as appropriate, free the referenced objects.

Comment: use nil instead of NULL - nil represents a null objective c object.  If you are not using ARC you'll have to do a [thisArray release]; to ensure cleanup.

Comment: Okay - thanks. I guess the same question applies to all pointers in objects to other objects? So even say for Appdelegate if I have a property pointer to an array - if app delegate is deleted by App closing, does my array property also automatically get deleted by ARC (along with it's contents).

Comment: Thanks Kirk - so nil when setting a pointer to an object to point to a 'no object'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NSArray/NSMutableArray only keeps a reference to the objects it contains, and by setting that array to NULL it will automatically releases all those references.  You don't have to cycle through them all to release them manually.